# Understanding lemma regarding fundamental class

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology

I am reading Class Field Theory from Milne's notes. I do not understand a couple of things from the following lemma about fundamental class: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf#X.3.2.7     (the link will take you to the lemma)

In the proof of the lemma, the author says [image]

I think by kernal-cokernal lemma he refers to Snake lemma. I do not understand what is meant by applying this lemma on the rows and that the lemma is functorial. I hence do not get how one gets the second commutative diagram from the first. Also, if I assume somehow that we get the second diagram by applying snake lemma, how do we recognize the maps in the diagram as $Inf$ or $Res$? Apriori they are just the maps we get from snake lemma.

Any help is appreciated and feel free to give any reference.

Comment: if the first row in the first diagram is $A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{g} C$ then the first row of the 2nd diag is $0\subset\ker f\subset\ker(g\circ f)\xrightarrow{f}\ker g$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, by the kernel-cokernel lemma he means the kernel-cokernel lemma p.87.

Contrary to the comment by Chin, this does answer the question. OP was misreading the text. Once this is corrected, everything should be clear.